# Wonder Woman's strength (2017 film) vs the comic books

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, comic-adaptation, wonder-woman

I noticed Wonder Woman is incredibly strong in the 2017 film, being able to pretty easily lift a tank over her head. The only other Wonder Woman I am familiar with was the Linda Carter TV series, where I don't remember her being that strong.

Does her strength and other powers reflect some of what the comic books series depict? I am assuming there are differences in her powers between and even within the various authors /series. I am just curious if she closely reflects at least one of the series.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this question is too broad. They are *dozens* of different interpretations of Wonder Woman in the comics based on different eras, retcons and the differing runs of different writers over the past 75 years. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman and http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_(Diana_Prince)

Comment: <comments removed> This question has been closed, but please do not use comments in lieu of posting a proper answer below. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is too broad. I am simply asking if the level of her strength is supported by any of comics. It is a yes or no question. Everyone has answered yes, answering my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She was able to lift a tank in *Injustice: Year One* #9:

[image]

And also handed Superman his a** in *Injustice: Yer Four* #8 and #9:

[image]

And was able to go toe-to-toe with him in *New 52* (though I can't identify the issue right now):

[image]

In the animated *Justice League: War* she was also able to sustain heavy blows by Darkseid, and then trade blows with him. My point: ever since she was introduced as a daughter of Zeus, she's been more than able to bully Superman in a fight, and her superior warrior training made it look easy.

Answer (score 5):

While the *plot* of the the 2017 *Wonder Woman* movie movie is drawn from one of her very earliest comics, the *character* of Diana Prince appears to be based heavily on her most recent incarnation, from the "New 52" era. This would track with the other DCEU movies, which are based on the more modern (often darker and grittier) versions of the characters.

In the post-Flashpoint New 52 comics, Diana is (as we find out in the movie)

> a demi-god, the daughter of Zeus

and as such, she has an *incredible* amount of power. In fact, the bracers that she wears in the movie are (in the source material) specifically designed to weaken her, so that she does not inadvertently kill everyone she fights. Even with those bracers, she is shown capable of going toe-to-toe with Superman. Lifting a tank is fairly minor compared to, for example, holding an entire airplane off the ground to save the people in it (which she's done).

Answer (score 5):

The various powers/abilities/motives/motifs of characters in comic books changes depending on the time period, who's writing them, among other things. Superman for instance used to simply have superhuman strength and invulnerability, and got around by running and leaping long distances (he can leap tall buildings in a single bound!), and primarily gained his ability to fly due to radio show depictions, and then because it was cheaper (and less silly, apparently) to animate flying than leaping for the original Fleischer cartoons. At one point his powers were considered standard for Kryptonians even before Krypton was destroyed, but was later retconned to be a side effect of being exposed to earth's yellow sun (Krypton had a red sun).

As such, consider the depictions of Wonder Woman you're referencing, specifically comparing modern versions to the Lynda Carter version of the 1970s TV show. Showing superhuman strength such as hurtling tanks and large objects is a costly endeavor, more so when you have to rely on more practical effects because it's the 1970s. In general, though, Diana has typically been depicted as having strength on par with that of Superman.

Characters and their depictions change over time, depending on who's writing them, what era they're in, and even what budgets for the medium will allow.

Comment: Good point about the cost of her special effects.